# auto sort table with x max columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Background:**

I am using jquery/ajax to dynamically add or remove columns to a table row.

When the table column count reaches 4, I create a new table row then add the column to it.

```
var last_col_count = $('#myTable tr:last').children().length;

//if last row has less than 4 columns then append row with new column
if (last_col_count < 4) {
  $('#myTable > tbody > tr:last').append("<td>...</td>");
} else {
  //table row reached 4 columns, append new table row and add column
  $('#myTable tbody').append("<tr><td>...</td></tr>");
}
```

**Issue:**

This above works but there is a gap in the logic for when I need to start removing columns from the rows, I then end up with an uneven amount of columns on each row.

For example: lets say I have a table with 3 rows and 4 columns each.

```
_____ COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
ROW1 |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
ROW2 |  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |
ROW3 |  I  |  J  |  K  |  L  |
```

If I remove a column from the first row then I end up with 3 uneven rows

```
_____ COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
ROW1 |  A  |  B  |  C  |
ROW2 |  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |
ROW3 |  I  |  J  |  K  |  L  |
```

**Requirement:**

How can I make sure the table is always sorted to have 4 columns per row?

Example of desired outcome following the above scenario (removing table column "D"):

```
_____ COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
ROW1 |  A  |  B  |  C  |  E  |
ROW2 |  F  |  G  |  H  |  I  |
ROW3 |  J  |  K  |  L  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked around, it seems the cleaner approach would be to use responsive css & div's

Working solution and code here:
https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/responsive-multi-column-lists-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, why not just use placeholders for empty cells so that a row is always containing four columns? If a cell really doesn't need to be in a specific row, you would have to rebuild the entire table again for each deletion. Maybe have a look at some jQuery table libs if those offer your requested automatic ordering behavior.

Comment: Correct. The cells are not required to in any particular order so no placeholders.